# Can't get AJAX post to send ID value to PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I used this same code on a different input and it works fine. However I can't get this to work. I can't get the post action to send the value from the select menu and echo the value of the variable.

**HTML code:**

```
<select type="text" id="typeofpayment" class="form-control" placeholder='Payment Method'>
<option>Choose Payment Method</option>
<option value= "1">Cash</option>
<option value="2">Check</option>
<option value="3">Credit Card</option>
<option value="4">Paypal</option>
</select>           
<div id='loadinvoice'></div>
<div id='loadinvoice2'></div>
```

**JS Script**

```
(document).ready(function(){
$('input#datepaid').on('change',function(){
$.post( "typeofpayment.php", $( 'select#typeofpayment' ).serialize(), function( data ){
alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
$( "#loadinvoice2" ).html( data );
});
});
});
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
echo 'hello';
$typeofpayment= $_POST['typeofpayment'];
echo '$typeofpayment';
?>
```

Comment: You should serialize your form, not your select, and give your select a name, not just an id.

Comment: You have `$('input#datepaid').on('change'`, but don't see a input with id `datepaid`. Have you verified that your `.on('change'` has occurred, and that your `$.post()` has fired? What does your browser console say?

Comment: sry about that. it does fire and return the echo 'hello' but no variable value

Comment: serialize won't get the id you need to grab that with `.attr('id')`

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `.serialize()`? Have you tried `$('select#typeofpayment').val()` -> `$.post( "typeofpayment.php", {typeofpayment: $('select#typeofpayment').val()}, function( data ){...`

Comment: this worked great. I guess I misread the jquery docs. put it in an answer and I'll vote it up

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
Html code:

```
<select type="text" id="typeofpayment" name="typeofpayment" class="form-control" placeholder='Payment Method'>
<option>Choose Payment Method</option>
<option value="1">Cash</option>
<option value="2">Check</option>
<option value="3">Credit Card</option>
<option value="4">Paypal</option>
</select>
<div id='loadinvoice'></div>
<div id='loadinvoice2'></div>
```

Js code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#typeofpayment').on('change',function(){
        $.post( "typeofpayment.php", $( 'select#typeofpayment' ).serialize(), function( data ){
            alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
            $( "#loadinvoice2" ).html( data );
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
echo 'hello ';
$typeofpayment= $_POST['typeofpayment'];
echo $typeofpayment;
?>
```